# For DJing, I want to have two distinct audio outputs, both connected to a single USB port. Does the hardware exist?

Tags: usb, audio

Very simple device I'm searching for but doesn't seem to exist.

It has usb on one end, preferably USB C.  On the other end it has two different .3mm audio jacks.  They don't play the same audio, they can each be selected to output different things.

Typically I would use a single adapter and my built in port, but this introduces a lot of issues due to recent Apple regressions.  In short, outputs on a usb adapter always exist, but the headphones port only exists when something is plugged into it.  Having to plug in audio cables before being able to choose outputs forces me to make these decisions on stage, rather than being able to select them before.

Comment: Best I've come up with so far is a USB-C -> 2x USB-C adapter, each having a USB-C to 3mm female aux.  It should work, though it feels very clunky for such a simple concept.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: I think technically it would be possible to get two distinct audio signals through a single jack if you seperate L and R, but then you are only getting mono signals

Comment: What is the host device you're using? An apple device of some kind with a USB-C port? Or is this some DJ deck with a USB port on it?

Comment: I'm using a laptop.  I've come up with a solution and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with what I think will work just fine.  It's a USB-C doubler, and two Single Port USB Sound Cards:

[image]

It's a lot more expensive than I would think something like this would be, but it should do the trick.  Also of note, this was a surprisingly confusing concept when I asked on a DJing subreddit as well as here.  Most DJs buy big expensive boards that have multiple audio out, and the one's who travel light are radio silence.

Comment: You need to double check if that splitter actually does what you think it does. It says "OTG" which might mean it's hard-wired to work only with devices that have USB OTG ports (phones and tablets). It might be dual-use and work with normal USB host ports, or maybe not.

Comment: Thanks for the concern!  The product photos and user reviews show it being attached to a laptop and two peripherals.  Link here: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07TPS44SL